# How to use SESSION with a login to a php website that checks usernames from a DB

Tags: mysql, authentication, session-cookies

I need a simple website (like a simple forum) login, and I have a mysql "users" table that I need to check the user's submitted "username" against for validity.  Once they log in to the site it should track their session on the site.  I am a newbie so am not sure how to do this other than needing to use the session state function.

I was thinking of a simple "login" form with a query to call the "users" array from the DB, and then use if in array to check the validity, but I really am at a loss of how to tackle this.  I can really use suggestions.
tnx...

Comment: Just check the user name and password against the database. If they are there then set the session up in a way to say they are logged in. I would also be inclined to save the session id to a table so you can check on page requests for people trying to change their cookies to appear logged in, and this also makes it easy for you to disconnect a particular user at will (you just delete the record of their session id on the table of current logged in users)

Comment: Tnx for the reply!  What I don't know how to do is the right code sequence/syntax.  After I check their user account against the DB user table using a simple form, how do I initiate the session?  Is it merely add a session_state function code line right after the "true" username authentication?  Also, my form code is      <input type='hidden' name='username' " . " value='$username'>
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Login">   Can the two input tags be used like this?  Tnx

Comment: Generally start the session at the start of the script. Set the variables in the session that you want after you have checked the user table, and save the session id in a table if required.